# How do I specifically change Intellij Idea theme color for version update window?

Tags: intellij-idea

I recently changed my Intellij Idea theme to use a custom theme, then have been tweaking it to fit my personal preferences.

I've fixed most of the deficiencies in usability/readablity but am still running into issues in the popup window that comes up when you click the update button:

[image: Update modal]

What comes up is completely unreadable:

[image: Update confirm modal]

So the question is: Where is the setting for overriding the colors in this window? This is pretty much the last problem I have with my custom theme, and I've combed through the settings trying to determine how to change this to no avail.

Note: If this is the wrong stack exchange site to ask this question, let me know the correct one and I'll move it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is known issue: [IDEA-227157](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-227157) that has been fixed for 2020.2.X versions (release is planned in the end of July of 2020).

Comment: So known issue but only for certain themes I guess.  Weird.